# meijer g function explicit form

Tags: special-functions, closed-form

Can the following case of the Meijer G-function
$$
G_{2,3}^{3,1}\left(z\left|\begin{smallmatrix}0,1\\
0,0,0\end{smallmatrix}\right.\right)
$$
be expressed more explicitly (in terms of other special functions, but involving no infinite integrals)?
This question seems to be related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311583/has-someone-seen-a-discussion-of-the-divergent-summation-of-sum-limits-k-0/351836#351836), [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715479/conjectured-closed-form-of-g22-33-left1-middle-beginarrayc1-1b1-b), and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330223/the-solution-for-an-integral-including-exponential-integral-function/383928#383928).

Answer (score 2):

With some help from *Mathematica*:
$$G_{2,3}^{3,1}\left(z\left|
\begin{smallmatrix}
 0,1 \\
 0,0,0 \\
\end{smallmatrix}
\right.\right) = -2 z \, {_3F_3}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1,1,1\\2,2,2\end{smallmatrix}\middle|\,z\right)-\frac{1}{2}
   \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\left.{_1F_1}\left(\begin{smallmatrix}t\\1\end{smallmatrix}\middle|\,z\right)\right|_{t=0}+ 
   \left(\operatorname{Ei}(z)+\tfrac{1}{2}\ln\left(\tfrac1z\right)\right)\left(\gamma+\ln(z)\right)-\frac{\gamma}{2}\ln (z)-\frac{\gamma^2}{2}+\frac{\pi ^2}{4}.$$

Comment: How did you arrive at this answer though?

Comment: @Jason By using the `FunctionExpand[MeijerG[{{0}, {1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {}}, z]]` *Mathematica* command.